# Hint to solve $\int_0^\infty\frac{e^{-x\pi}}{1+sech{(x\pi)}}dx=-\ln\left(\frac{2}{e}\right)^{\frac{2}{\pi}}$

Tags: integration

$$\int_0^\infty\frac{e^{-x\pi}}{1+sech{(x\pi)}}dx=-\ln\left(\frac{2}{e}\right)^{\frac{2}{\pi}}$$

Can anyone give me a hint on to how to go about solving this integral?

Comment: Hint: $ \textrm{sech}(x\pi) $ is a rational function of $ u = e^{-x\pi} $.

Comment: Ok let me try using that

Comment: I end up with $\frac{1}{\pi}\int_0^1\frac{u^2+1}{(u+1)^2}du$

Comment: Still I need more help on how to integrate this one

Comment: Do you know how to use partial fraction decomposition?

Comment: No, I don't, this is where I am stuck

Answer (score 2, accepted):

We have
$$\text{sech}(\pi x) = \dfrac2{e^{\pi x} + e^{-\pi x}}$$
Hence, the integrand becomes
$$\dfrac{e^{-\pi x}}{1+\dfrac2{e^{\pi x} + e^{-\pi x}}} = \dfrac{1+e^{-2\pi x}}{e^{\pi x} + e^{-\pi x}+2}$$
Setting $e^{-\pi x} = t$, we obtain the integral to be
\begin{align}
I & = \int_1^{0}\dfrac{1+t^2}{t+1/t+2}\left(-\dfrac{dt}{\pi t}\right) = \dfrac1{\pi}\int_0^1 \dfrac{t^2+1}{(t+1)^2}dt = \dfrac1{\pi}\int_0^1\left(1-\dfrac{2}{1+t} + \dfrac2{(1+t)^2}\right)dt\\
& = \dfrac1{\pi}\left(1-2\ln2 + 1\right) = \dfrac2{\pi} \ln\left(\dfrac{e}2\right)
\end{align}

Answer (score 0):

As Starfall commented, change variable $$e^{\pi x}=u\implies x=\frac{\log (u)}{\pi }\implies dx=\frac{1}{\pi  u}$$ So, $$\int\frac{e^{-x\pi}}{1+\text{sech}{(\pi x)}}dx=\int\frac{u^2+1}{\pi  \left(u^2+u\right)^2}\,du$$ Use partial fraction decomposition and get a series of simple terms to be integrated.